# Hibernate : delete child entity with two different kinds of parent entities

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have a data base schema like in the picture [DB schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66u8g.png) where 1 child entity has 2 different kinds of ManyToOne relations to different parents: father and mother. When I let this be created by Hibernate, I can delete a child by removing it from the mother, but I can not delete it by removing it from the father.

The father entity looks like this, and the mother is identical.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "father_entity")
public class FatherEntity extends BaseEntity {
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "fatherEntity", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
private Collection<ChildEntity> childEntities = new ArrayList<>();

public void addChildEntity(ChildEntity childEntity) {
    this.childEntities.add(childEntity);
    childEntity.setFatherEntity(this);
}

public void removeChildEntity(ChildEntity childEntityToRemove) {
    Iterator<ChildEntity> iterator = this.childEntities.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        ChildEntity childEntity = iterator.next();

        if (childEntity.equals(childEntityToRemove)) {
            iterator.remove();
            childEntityToRemove.setFatherEntity(null);
        }
    }
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "grand_parent_entity_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
private GrandParentEntity grandParentEntity;

@Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
private String name;
```

The child class is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "child_entity")
public class ChildEntity extends BaseEntity {

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "father_entity_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
private FatherEntity fatherEntity;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "mother_entity_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
private MotherEntity motherEntity;

@Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
private String name;
```

So basically with this in place, this test succeeds, as expected:

```
@Test
void testCascadeRemove2() {
    assertThat(fatherEntityRepository.count()).isEqualTo(1l);
    assertThat(motherEntityRepository.count()).isEqualTo(1l);
    assertThat(childEntityRepository.count()).isEqualTo(1l);
    assertThat(fatherEntity.getChildEntities().contains(childEntity));
    
    motherEntity.removeChildEntity(childEntity);
    
    assertThat(fatherEntityRepository.count()).isEqualTo(1l);
    assertThat(motherEntityRepository.count()).isEqualTo(1l);
    assertThat(childEntityRepository.count()).isEqualTo(0l);
    assertThat(fatherEntity.getChildEntities().isEmpty());
}
```

But this symmetrical one gives an error, from which I deduct that the child was not removed, but only its foreign key to the father was set to null:

```
@Test
void testCascadeRemove1() {
    assertThat(fatherEntityRepository.count()).isEqualTo(1l);
    assertThat(motherEntityRepository.count()).isEqualTo(1l);
    assertThat(childEntityRepository.count()).isEqualTo(1l);
    assertThat(motherEntity.getChildEntities().contains(childEntity));
    
    fatherEntity.removeChildEntity(childEntity);
    
    assertThat(fatherEntityRepository.count()).isEqualTo(1l);
    assertThat(motherEntityRepository.count()).isEqualTo(1l);
    assertThat(childEntityRepository.count()).isEqualTo(0l);
    assertThat(motherEntity.getChildEntities().isEmpty());
}
```

The error:

```
Hibernate: insert into father_entity (grand_parent_entity_id, name) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into mother_entity (grand_parent_entity_id, name) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into child_entity (father_entity_id, mother_entity_id, name) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select count(*) as col_0_0_ from father_entity fatherenti0_
Hibernate: select count(*) as col_0_0_ from mother_entity motherenti0_
Hibernate: select count(*) as col_0_0_ from child_entity childentit0_
Hibernate: select count(*) as col_0_0_ from father_entity fatherenti0_
Hibernate: select count(*) as col_0_0_ from mother_entity motherenti0_
Hibernate: update child_entity set father_entity_id=?, mother_entity_id=?, name=? where id=?
2020-07-30 16:53:46.049  WARN 10068 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  
SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23502
2020-07-30 16:53:46.050 ERROR 10068 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper 
ERROR: null value in column "father_entity_id" violates not-null constraint
Detail: Failing row contains (52, child, null, 52).
```

Does anyone know why the one parent can delete the child by removing it from its list, and the other cannot?

Thanks